# Android - Location Manager requestLocationUpdates bottleneck

Tags: java, android, cordova, background-process

I have an Android background service that report positions from time to time. When I test locally over wifi it works pretty well, however when testing in 3G connection for example (sometimes on Edge) I have perceived that the application apparently enters in a bottleneck and do not execute the ***onLocationChanged*** method. That's okay because maybe lost signal or so on. However after a while (maybe when connection is re-established) it start updating all requests at once, in a matter of a few seconds many many times the method ***onLocationChanged*** is executed.

Does anyone have ideas how to solve that? Is it possible to add timeout into the method **locationManager.requestLocationUpdates**?

**My Listener**

```
public class MyListener implements LocationListener {
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //report location to server
        HttlCallToUpdatePostion(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude, loc.Accuracy);
  }
}
```

**My Service**

```
Handler handler = null;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyListener listener = new MyListener();

protected void doWork() {
  Looper.prepare();
  handler = new Handler();
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, listener);
  Looper.loop();
}
```

Comment: "This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a *network lookup*." means that it needs an internet connection to lookup where your current wifi or GSM cell is located. It can't give you location updates if your phone turns all internet connectivity off while at sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app, exactly what you need.
When it was a service only I met the same problem. While the UI went to background and screen off the service went to background and it scheduled the system calls, once when triggered the buffer was flushed and I had like 10-50 updates.

The solution it is: an Alarm must be set and scheduled with 5000 value and a BroadcastRreceiver will receive and it will handle properly. Than you will meet other problems, which is not asked here.

For me this was a SOLUTION and the app is in use!

Edit:
Alarm setup code part:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
// In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request
        // code instead of 192837
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), timerInterval, sender);
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".broadcastreceiver.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

class implementation part:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        ...
```

Comment: I have used an Alarm at beginning, however had problems to stop the Alarm when needed (I'm newbie in Android) and found this approach with Looper, that aparently would work as expected. Do you have any example how to do that? any idea of which type of problem I can face using Alarm? btw, Thanks for now!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)  AlarmManager.cancel() will cancel your alarm

Answer (score 0):

check for **power saving mode** in adorid system setting: it must be disable to permit location manager to generete update location  when the screen is off